# BigQuery - Correlated subquery unnesting array not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to join array elements in BigQuery but I am getting the following error message: `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.`

Imagine I have two mapping tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.field_id_name` (
  id STRING,
  name STRING
) AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
     [STRUCT("s1", "string1"),
     STRUCT("s2", "string2"),
     STRUCT("s3", "string3")]
  )
)
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.field_values` (
  id STRING,
  name STRING
) AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
     [STRUCT("v1", "val1"),
     STRUCT("v2", "val2"),
     STRUCT("v3", "val3")]
  )
)
```

And I have the following as input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.input` AS
  SELECT [
    STRUCT<id STRING, value ARRAY<STRING>>("s1", ["v1"]),
    STRUCT("s2", ["v1"]),
    STRUCT("s3", ["v1"])
  ] records
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [
    STRUCT("s1", ["v1", "v2"]),
    STRUCT("s2", ["v1", "v2"]),
    STRUCT("s3", ["v1", "v2"])
  ]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [
    STRUCT("s1", ["v1", "v2", "v3"]),
    STRUCT("s2", ["v1", "v2", "v3"]),
    STRUCT("s3", ["v1", "v2", "v3"])
  ]
```

I am trying to produce this output:

```
SELECT [
  STRUCT<id_mapped STRING, value_mapped ARRAY<STRING>>("string1", ["val1"]),
  STRUCT("string2", ["val1"]),
  STRUCT("string3", ["val1"])
] records
UNION ALL
SELECT [
  STRUCT("string1", ["val1", "val2"]),
  STRUCT("string2", ["val1", "val2"]),
  STRUCT("string3", ["val1", "val2"])
]
UNION ALL
SELECT [
  STRUCT("string1", ["val1", "val2", "val3"]),
  STRUCT("string2", ["val1", "val2", "val3"]),
  STRUCT("string3", ["val1", "val2", "val3"])
]
```

However the following query is failing with the correlated subqueries error.

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT
      STRUCT(fin.name, ARRAY(SELECT fv.name FROM UNNEST(value) v JOIN test.field_values fv ON (v = fv.id)))
    FROM UNNEST(records) r
    JOIN test.field_id_name fin ON (fin.id = r.id)
  )
FROM test.input
```

Comment: please present sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant - added sample data with desired transformation

Comment: looks very messy to me :o(    I cannot even match sample data with query provided! Can yo please rewrite your question such that we can clearly see 1) input data sample 2) expected output sample matching presented input 3) code you have so far and what he problem you have with it

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I have modified the question, hope that's clearer!

Comment: from quick glance - looks much better now. will look more closer later when have time (unless someone will already answer it) :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id AS id_mapped, val AS value_mapped)) AS records
FROM (
  SELECT fin.name AS id, ARRAY_AGG(fv.name) AS val, FORMAT('%t', t) id1, FORMAT('%t', RECORD) id2
  FROM `test.input` t,
  UNNEST(records) record,
  UNNEST(value) val
  JOIN `test.field_id_name` fin ON record.id = fin.id
  JOIN `test.field_values` fv ON val = fv.id
  GROUP BY id, id1, id2
)
GROUP BY id1
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - returns exact output you expecting

Comment: Don't know how you come up with solutions like these. You're a magician

Comment: please consider voting up the answer  - this is important here on SO! :o) as of magician - when you do such things day after day for last about 40+ years - you don't do magic - you just mechanically apply patterns ... :o)